# Java not finding the proper path

Tags: java, cmd

I am having a problem with running java from cmd.exe.
When i type in 'java' this errors shows:

```
Error: could not open `D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'
```

The problem is, my java is not in jre6, but in jre7. The jre6 folder doesn't even exist anymore.

I've checked the path and all other environmental variables and java was not mentioned anywhere. So I updated path to point to D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin but that didn't help.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit so I also tried running java from 64-bit cmd.exe but it didn't help.

Is there anywhere else except path to look and change the way Windows looks for java?

Comment: If you do the commands `where java` and `java -version`, what is the output?

Comment: Have you set Environmental Variable ?, and if so have you done it properly ?

Comment: As the answer below stated, the problem was with leftover executables in system32. After those were deleted, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that older JDKs copy `java.exe` among some other Java executables into `C:\Windows\System32` which happens to be on the `PATH` before the new JDK/JRE location.

The solution is to delete `java.exe` and other Java related executables from `System32` as they aren't required any more. This could however potentially break applications that depend on the older JDK/JRE and hence they may need to be re-configured.

Comment: This solved the problem, I had already done this, but somehow executables reapeared in system32.